# PHP Script Flow Help Guidance

Tags: php

Not looking for written code, just advise on how or what is needed to do what I explain. This is the hardest part, conveying my idea into what I need to be able to do it not knowing what functions would do it.

I want to execute PHP script A by a simple http web call. No big deal. Inside script A I want it to execute script B, which I know how to do, and I want it to also execute script C, but only execute script C once in a 60 second time-frame, no matter how many times script A is called on, because script A will be called on many times in that time frame and continually needs to execute script B. When 60 seconds (or whatever I want to designate) has passed then script A resets itself so that script C is executable once more in a new 60 second time-frame. Timers = sleep(x). So what do I need to do so script A so that it maybe excludes executing script C in the 60 second time after it executes it once? Like the code to execute script C would be "locked out" or passed over. What functions should I be looking into to learn this? Structure is killing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Record the time you call C in a session variable and don't allow A to call C until 60 seconds has passed since that time. At the top of A (it needs to happen before any output from the script) add:

```
session_start();
```

when you want to call C, use something like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['c_call_time']) || $_SESSION['c_call_time'] < time() - 60) {
    $_SESSION['c_call_time'] = time();
    // call C
}
```

@user655685 raises a valid point about the script possibly being called by different users, and the time limit applying separately to each of them. If this is a problem, you could work around it by declaring custom session handlers that used the same storage location for all users. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) for a description of how to do that (in their example, you would ignore the `$id` parameter passed to the `read` and `write` callbacks).

Comment: Hmm, looks like a great idea. I am familiar with the basic use of session variable. In this case it is used as a time comparator. I am the only user so session invoked would only pertain to me. I am using this call to C once, to dial the Linphone, so we don't want to dial the Linphone every time A is hit. B logs incoming phone number and text message from Twilio when Twilio hits A. IVR then parses the text file generated by B. Linphone is what "starts up" IVR on the very first inbound text message from Twilio to A..Neat, eh? You gave me what I asked for, thank you very much!

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project! Glad I was able to be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions would solve this problem , but if the script is called by another user this would break , since php runs each environment saperate on php alone this would be impossible. You will have to either create an outside variable (ie file) or database entry which tracks when this was last run and then delete the file every minute ( file / database entry to have time stamp of last run)